# How to edit catalog product view?

Tags: magento2

how to edit this product catalog view?

[image: Producto catalog view]"

I've been trying but all I find is to edit the individual product page

Answer (score 0):

You can find layout file with name as `catalog_category_view.xml` in magento_catalog and phtml file is `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml`.